# Issue with generate Rooms use Model Devaritive API

Tags: autodesk-forge, autodesk-model-derivative

I'm facing with problem APS API generate room is incorect.

This is generated by APS, 3 room from Revit Model combine into one:

[image]

But reality in Revit Model, it not like this, `CV CHAMBER` Room just is small part, and the big room at center is `AHU`
[image]

Any limitation when I use api translate room ? Can I know the main reason for that ?

Any help is appreciated !